# Downloading Binary to return a PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, download, binary-data

I am trying to get some code which i can feed a link and get a pdf downloaded from the link. I have the downloading process working, but I think I download the data in binary instead of a pdf so that I can't view it.

Here is the code that I am currently using. This code downloads a pdf, but that pdf is unreadable if one tries to open it. I've included operations for This code is for Python 3.

```
import requests
pdf_url = "http://url.pdf"

r = requests.get(pdf_url, stream = True)

with open("python.pdf","wb") as pdf:
     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
          if chunk:
               pdf.write(chunk)
```

I'm looking for a solution that will either allow me to download the pdf or translate the binary into a readable format.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:c]? Also, "I download the data in binary instead of a pdf" doesn't make much sense because _every bit (pun not intended) of software and other data on your computer is binary_: PDFs, images, programs, music - _everything_.

Comment: What happens if you paste that same URL into a browser?  What happens if you look at the file downloaded by your python (not `C`!) code in Notepad?  Is it a text page saying something like authentication required?

Comment: That code works for me. I set `pdf_url` to the URL of some random PDF file, ran the script, and the output file was a readable PDF file. Your problem must be elsewhere?